# C# Regex match the last digit after the last underscore

Tags: c#, regex

Using regex I'm trying to get only the last digit (can be only 2 or 3) after the last underscore.

What I have right now is getting the digit and characters.
I need to cut off the characters and only get the digit [2-3].

Here is my example -- I need to get only 2 after the last underscore. Currently getting both digit and characters

```
ABC_0000_DEFG_1I_23_45_HIJKL2.pdf
```

```
The output I want -- 2 (after HIJKL).

^.*_\K[^.]+

If I get rid of ^ with \d, d{2-3}, ... it still gets HIJKL.
```

Comment: string pattern = @"\d";
            string input = "ABC_0000_DEFG_1I_23_45_HIJKL2.pdf";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            string results = match.Value;

Comment: The pattern is not static, it can be vary. That's just an example.

Comment: Searching from right to left the pattern gets first digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression

```
_[^_]*([2-3])[^_]*$
```

should do you. It matches:

- `_` — an underscore, followed by
- `[^_]*` — zero or more characters other than underscore, followed by
- `([23])` — the decimal digits `2` or `3`, followed by
- `[^_]*` — zero or more characters other than underscore, followed by
- `$` — end-of-text

You will need to get match group #1:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"_[^_]*([2-3])[^_]*$");
var m  = rx.Match("ABC_0000_DEFG_1I_23_45_HIJKL2.pdf");
var s  = m.Success ? m.Groups(1) : null;
```

At which point, `s` should be "2".

Comment: Output for this is _HIJKL2.pdf

I need only 2

Comment: You have to capture the bit you want and reference that via `Match.Groups`. See amended answer.

Comment: Thanks! just used Groups[1] to get the output I wanted. Accepted your answer as well. I have one more question.. If I have a string that has characters and decimal numbers.. for example) blah(space)blah(space)blah(space)11.11%(space)22.22%(space)33.33%(space)44.44%(space)55.55%  and so on... (could have more numbers) Is there a way to get the highest decimal without  the % using Regex? or do I have to just split and get the outcome I want?

Comment: That's a different question... which you should ask separately.

Comment: It's fine. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
_[^_]*(\d)[^_]*$
```

Which matches the last underscore, followed by a digit surrounded by anything but underscores.

You can use `[23]` instead of `\d` if you want to ignore anything other than `2` or `3`.

Comment: Still prints out the whole text after the last underscore

Comment: You would need to use the capture groups, as noted in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To get a match only in .NET you might also use lookarounds:

```
(?<=_[^_]*)[23](?=[^_]*$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=_[^_]*)` Positive lookbehind, assert `_` followed by optional chars other than `_`
- `[23]` Match either 2 or 3
- `(?=[^_]*$)` Positive lookahead to assert no `_` till the end of the string

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d_%5b%5e_%5d*%29%5b23%5d%28%3f%3d%5b%5e_%5d*%24%29&i=ABC_0000_DEFG_1I_23_45_HIJKL2.pdf) or a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cjMKzB).

Example code

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=_[^_]*)[23](?=[^_]*$)");
Match match = regex.Match("ABC_0000_DEFG_1I_23_45_HIJKL2.pdf");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output

```
2
```